# Legacy mode, Grub can't load win8 even it's in grub list

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I don't think I can handle daul-boot in UEFI mode, so I delete `efi` floder in Win8 iso as Microsoft suggests to install win8 in legacy mode. Then turn to install Ubuntu. I create some unallocated space in Win8 and install my ubuntu in as logic partition and mount at `/`.

The problem is when I restart my laptop(Lenovo E440), I can see grub and I can see windows 8 right there, I can enter Win8 this time. But if I reboot again and try ubuntu, **win8 will not load even it's in grub**. I used ubuntu liveCD to boot-repair, same problem.

[here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10666788/) is the detail information generated by boot-repair.
Secure-boot is disabled, boot option is legacy-only.

I know there are many this kinda of issues in internet. But I can't find a solution. I have do this OS installation work for two days, feel disappointed.

-------EDIT--------

I finally make it. Daul-boot in UEFI mode by following this [guide](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html).

Besides, I recommand [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to make a UEFI bootable Win8 usb.

Leave this question here, since install win8+ubuntu is not a very happy thing. And this guide is testes by myself. Hope helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Windows **8.1** or **8** ?
Because Windows 8.1 is the worsе edition of Windows I'd ever tried. It doesn't support many useful programs of Windows 8 and Windows 7 (You can just emulate Win 7 and 8, but as you know, it very bad affects to the perfomance). It doesn't work "very well".

And the second possible problem is in repairing of grub.

In your BIOS, disable QuickBoot/FastBoot and Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT). Also disable FastStartup (for Windows 8).

Sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: I am using 8.1. I disable quick boot as you side, but I still have this issue. The strange thing is `sometimes` when I rescure grub, win 8 is loadable.

Comment: @hakunami 8.1 might work with errors. Do you have a disk of windows 8.1? (NOT PIRATE - pirate version of win 8.1 doesn't work, I'd tried it)

Comment: if you have a disk you can install ubuntu first and win 8.1 second, and after that reinstall grub with win 8.1.([how to reinstall grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)) @hakunami

Comment: Hi, I updated the question. Finally install win8.1+ubuntu14.04 in UEFI mode.

Comment: yes you are right, this is not a good idea. Ubuntu doesn't see installed windows and that's why it is not workin'. I had the same problem and just installed Ubuntu and deleted windows 7. @hakunami